# "Preserve the meets" definition on *Bell & Slomson Models and Ultraproducts*

Tags: order-theory

The books says as following (p.21):

> Let $\{A_n : n < \omega\}$ be a countable collection of subsets of a
> Boolean algebra ech having an infumum. Say for $n<\omega$, $a_n =
>  \inf(A_n)$. An ultrafilter $F$ in $B$ is said to preserve the meets
> iff for $n < \omega$, $h(a_n) = \inf \{ h(a): a \in A_n \}$ where $h$
> is the canonical homomorphism of $B$ onto $B/F \cong 2$ .

My question is where does the collection $A_n$ come from? Is the property of "preserving meets" relative to a given collection $A_n$? Or is it expected to work with any collection $\{ A_n\}$? If the latter case, what is the necessity of talking about colletions $\{A_n\}$? Isn't it equivalent (and simpler) to just say that $F$ preserve meets iff for any given collection $A$, $h(\inf A) = \inf \{ h(a): a \in A)\}$?

Comment: For me it seems relative to the given subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If actually says:

> Say $$\text{for }n<\omega\qquad a_n=\inf(A_n).\tag{$\Pi$}$$ An ultrafilter $F$ in $B$ is said to *preserve* the meets $(\Pi)$ iff ... ,

so it is clearly referring to the specific meets labelled $(\Pi)$. Theorem $4.10$ that immediately follows also refers specifically to those meets.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned the labelling, however I still not sure if I understand correctly. Does it mean it is relative to the $A_n$ after all?

Comment: @Shiranai: Yes: they are talking about preserving that specific family of meets.

Comment: Thanks, it just clicked. Here's the source of my misunderstanding: I though $( \Pi )$ was the name of the condition, but it is instead the name of the collection of meets. Now it makes complete sense when compared with the usual meet-preservation I know from order theory.

Comment: @Shiranai: You’re welcome. I actually had the same initial thought, and it took me a moment to realize what was actually going on.